# I am completely new to c# mvc and have been almost desperate

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a single view for two tables so I could insert data in it, but been busting my 
head for some time with it, @item.Course.Title does not work apparently. Here is my code, any help 
is much appreciated:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }
}

public class Base : DbContext    
{        
    public Base() : base("Base") { }
    public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }
    public DbSet <Course> Course { get; set; }


public class StudentService
{
    public List<Student> ShowJointList()
  {
        using(var db = new Base())
        {
            return db.Student.Include("Course").ToList();
        }
    }


       public class JoinController : Controller

{
    StudentService service;
    public JoinController()
    {
        service = new StudentService();
    }

    // GET: Join
    public ActionResult Index(int idCourse)
    {
        return View(service.ShowJointList().FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == idCourse).Course);
    }
```

This is my view, it always says either - The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'idCourse' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in 'SrudentAndCourse.Controllers.JoinController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

or if I change to: int? IdCourse, the message is - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
@using SrudentAndCourse.Models

@model List<Student>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>   <tr> 
        <td>First Name</td>
         td>Last Name</td>
       <td>Course Title</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>                  
                    <td>@item.FirstName</td>
                    <td>@item.LastName</td>
                    <td>@item.Course.Title</td>
                </tr>                   
            }
```

Comment: The value you supply to that View is a "Course" of a single Student, not a "List of Student"

Comment: tnx, can you tell me what would you write?

Comment: OT Your setup means that first you get *all* students from the database, and then discard all but the first matching one. Better would be to do that filtering in the database, that is *before* the `.ToList()`.

Comment: A FirstOrDefault may return a `null` when nothing matches, so the `.Course` will fail then - which apparently happens.

Comment: As for how to fix: either supply the View with a list of students (for example just the result of ShowJointList), or rebuild the view to accept a single Course. Of course make sure you do supply one.

Comment: tnx, this may sound stupid, but I just do not have enough knowledge to do what you wrote, could you write your own solution if that's not he problem?  Tnx in advance regardless of what you do:)

Comment: By the way, that `b.Id` you were filtering on, is the Student.Id, that probably never matches the course Id

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your View is really what you want to show, an important line is

```
@model List<Student>
```

This means that you will supply this View with a List of Students, that you then can access in the view as `Model`.

You supply this value as the parameter of the View method. So one example would be

```
 return View(service.ShowJointList());
```

which would show all Students of every Course.

However, you supply a idCourse parameter, which (I assume) means that you want to show the students of a particular course. A quick and dirty filter would be:

```
 return View(service.ShowJointList().Where(s => s.Course.Id == idCourse).ToList());
```

Now you still pass Students to your View, but only ones that are assigned to the particular Course you selected. I am assuming that every Student has a Course, so you don't get NullReference problems here.

**HOWEVER**
Doing it this way (filtering after the method call) does mean that you first read *all* Students from the database into memory and only then filter. A better way would be to add a new service method to include that "Where" filter before the .ToList(), so you execute the filter in the database.

For example

```
public List<Student> ShowCourseStudentList(int idCourse)
{
    using(var db = new Base())
    {
        return db.Student.Include("Course")
               .Where(s => s.Course.Id == idCourse)
               .ToList();
    }
}
```

and of course in the controller method, use

```
return View(service.ShowCourseStudentList(idCourse));
```

Comment: tnx, will try to do it that way! - your effort is much appreciated!

Comment: still not being able to show data from the two tables (that is, course title and student firstname and lastname) in the same table...trying to create an application in which student applies on a certain course by inserting it's name and surname, and later on administrator will edit the application

Comment: It's difficult to see from here. Do you get the correct data from the database?  Set some breakpoints, debug your application and see whether you have the expected data everywhere